# Dúvida chamar método com If Java

Tags: java

Bom, estou fazendo um projeto da Faculdade e estou iniciando agora em java, a questão é o seguinte, eu tenho 2 tabelas no sql server e 2 classes distintas no java, que seriam pessoa fisica e pessoa juridica, o problema é o seguinte, eu estou tentando criar um if else, que capture um campo chamado tipo_cliente, e que ele defina onde os dados seriam inseridos, mas estou errando sempre no Else.
Ps: O Método de pessoa juridica está em outra classe, gostária de ajuda se possivel.
Segue abaixo o código

```
if (pessoafisica.getTipo_cliente().trim().equals("Pessoa Fisica")) {
Connection conn = conectarPrepareStatment();
//instrução Sql para inserir o cliente no banco de dados
String sql = "INSERT INTO PessoaFisica (cpf, rg, nome, rua, bairro, cidade, uf, cep, telefone, sexo, data_nascimento, id_fun)";
sql += "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
//preenchendo os valores
stmt.setString(1, pessoafisica.getCpf());
stmt.setString(2, pessoafisica.getNome());
stmt.setString(3, pessoafisica.getRg());
stmt.setString(4, pessoafisica.getRua());
stmt.setString(5, pessoafisica.getBairro());
stmt.setString(6, pessoafisica.getCidade());
stmt.setString(7, pessoafisica.getUf());
stmt.setString(8, pessoafisica.getCep());
stmt.setString(9, pessoafisica.getTelefone());
stmt.setString(10, pessoafisica.getSexo());
stmt.setString(11, pessoafisica.getData_nascimento());
stmt.setObject(12, pessoafisica.getFuncionario().getId());
//executando
stmt.execute();
stmt.close();
//encerrando a conexão
desconectar();
} else {
```

E Nesse Else eu gostaria que fosse "chamado" O método de pessoa juridica, que está na classe de dados de pessoa juridica, mas não estou conseguindo.

Answer (score 1):

Imaginando que sua classe se chama `PessoaJuridica` e que ela contenha o método `inserirDados()`, dentro do `else` você faria assim:

`PessoaJuridica pj = new PessoaJuridica() ;`
`pj.inserirDados();`

É essa sua dúvida?

Comment: Aparentemente consegui resolver, ficou assim: } else {
         ClientePessoaJuridicaDados pessoajuridica = new ClientePessoaJuridicaDados();
         pessoajuridica.cadastrarClientePJuridica(pessoajuridica);

Comment: Sim, reflete o exemplo que dei.

Comment: Agora tá ocorrendo outro problema, quando eu abro o construtor, e puxo o método, ele quer gerar outro método mas usando como parametro dados que vem da classe de dados e não da classe básica.

Comment: Crie uma nova pergunta com sua dúvida e, o mais importante, coloque o código que você está usando e especifique onde e qual o erro, ok?

Answer (score 1):

Estou supondo que o getTipo_cliente volte "Pessoa Juridica", se for diferente, como por exemplo, ter acento, favor alterar.
   Connection conn = conectarPrepareStatment();
                String sql = null;

```
            if (pessoafisica.getTipo_cliente().trim().equals("Pessoa Fisica")) {

                    //instrução Sql para inserir o cliente no banco de dados
                    sql = "INSERT INTO PessoaFisica (cpf, rg, nome, rua, bairro, cidade, uf, cep, telefone, sexo, data_nascimento, id_fun)";
                    sql += "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                    //preenchendo os valores
                    stmt.setString(1, pessoafisica.getCpf());
                    stmt.setString(2, pessoafisica.getNome());
                    stmt.setString(3, pessoafisica.getRg());
                    stmt.setString(4, pessoafisica.getRua());
                    stmt.setString(5, pessoafisica.getBairro());
                    stmt.setString(6, pessoafisica.getCidade());
                    stmt.setString(7, pessoafisica.getUf());
                    stmt.setString(8, pessoafisica.getCep());
                    stmt.setString(9, pessoafisica.getTelefone());
                    stmt.setString(10, pessoafisica.getSexo());
                    stmt.setString(11, pessoafisica.getData_nascimento());
                    stmt.setObject(12, pessoafisica.getFuncionario().getId());
            } else if (pessoafisica.getTipo_cliente().trim().equals("Pessoa Juridica")) {
                    Connection conn = conectarPrepareStatment();
                    //instrução Sql para inserir o cliente no banco de dados
                    String sql = "INSERT INTO PessoaJuridica (campos da tabela)";
                    sql += "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                    //preenchendo os valores
                    stmt.setString(...)
                    //preencha os campos finais
            }
            //executando
            stmt.execute();
            stmt.close();
            //encerrando a conexão
            desconectar();
```

Outra maneira é exportar o miolo para funções que fazem a inserção.

```
            if (pessoafisica.getTipo_cliente().trim().equals("Pessoa Fisica")) {

                inserirPessoaFisica(cpf, rg, nome, rua, bairro, cidade, uf, cep, telefone, sexo, data_nascimento, id_fun);
            } else if (pessoafisica.getTipo_cliente().trim().equals("Pessoa Juridica")) {
                inserirPessoaJuridica(campos de pessoa juridica);
            } 


            public void inserirPessoaFisica(String cpf , String rg, String nome, String rua, String bairro, 
                String cidade, String uf, String cep, String telefone, String sexo, String data_nascimento, 
                Object id_fun) throws Exception
                {
                    Connection conn = conectarPrepareStatment(); 

                    //instrução Sql para inserir o cliente no banco de dados
                    String sql = "INSERT INTO PessoaFisica (cpf, rg, nome, rua, bairro, cidade, uf, cep, telefone, sexo, data_nascimento, id_fun)";
                    sql += "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                    //preenchendo os valores
                    stmt.setString(1, pessoafisica.getCpf());
                    stmt.setString(2, pessoafisica.getNome());
                    stmt.setString(3, pessoafisica.getRg());
                    stmt.setString(4, pessoafisica.getRua());
                    stmt.setString(5, pessoafisica.getBairro());
                    stmt.setString(6, pessoafisica.getCidade());
                    stmt.setString(7, pessoafisica.getUf());
                    stmt.setString(8, pessoafisica.getCep());
                    stmt.setString(9, pessoafisica.getTelefone());
                    stmt.setString(10, pessoafisica.getSexo());
                    stmt.setString(11, pessoafisica.getData_nascimento());
                    stmt.setObject(12, pessoafisica.getFuncionario().getId());

                    //executando
                    stmt.execute();
                    stmt.close();
                    //encerrando a conexão
                    desconectar();
                }

                public void inserirPessoaJuridica(....) throws Exception
                {
                    Connection conn = conectarPrepareStatment(); 

                    //instrução Sql para inserir o cliente no banco de dados
                    String sql = "INSERT INTO PessoaJuridica (....nomes de campos....)";
                    sql += "VALUES (...? para cada campo...)";
                    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                    //preenchendo os valores dos campos
                    stmt.setString(1, ....

                    //executando
                    stmt.execute();
                    stmt.close();
                    //encerrando a conexão
                    desconectar();
                }

            }
```